# Can an unlicensed user access a Lightning component from a managed package?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, managed-package

We have a Lightning component in a managed package. This component is meant to be used on Community pages. When the Community page is accessed by a Licensed user then everything works fine. This is because they have a license to our managed package.

If an unlicensed user tries to access the Community page with the component embedded then it does not work. We get the following error:

> The Apex Class MyComponentController is part of the AppExchange
>   Package MyPackage, and requires a license to use.

Any idea how to get around this?

I am not asking how to provide access to an Apex class to unauthorized users. This question is also not related to the interface being implemented by the component. **I am asking how to provide access to authenticated but unlicensed users.** Licensing and permission model are different things.